# I want to change the 35th character in a text file using python using a user input (character)

Tags: python-3.8

Below is the code

```
try:
    Untitled = open("Untitled.txt")
    A = Untitled.read()
    print(A)

except (FileNotFoundError):
    print("File not found")
    quit()
    
Change = input("\nEnter New Character: ")
f = A.replace(A[34],Change)

try:
   Untitled = open("Untitled copy.txt","x")

except(FileExistsError):
   print("File already exists")


try:
   Untitled = open("Untitled copy.txt","w")

except(FileNotFoundError):
   print("File not found")


A.write(f)
print(f)
```

The error message I get is this : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Please help me Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that strings in python are `immutable` which means that they cannot be changed in place.  However, you can overwrite the same string variable any time.

Form your code, after assign the input parameter use

```
A = A[:34] + Change + A[:-1]
```

This bit of code should work fine as long as A has a length 35 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling A.write, when you should be calling Untitled.write.

```
Untitled.write(f)
print(f)
```

This is because `A` is a string and `Untitled` is the variable you defined at line 21.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is wrong with the code?

1. The `f = A.replace(A[34],Change)` will replace *all* occurences of character at file position `34` with `Change`. For example, see:

```
In [3]: content = '123456789012345678901234567890123457890'

In [4]: content.replace(content[34], ' ')
Out[4]: '1234 678901234 678901234 678901234 7890'
```

What you want probably to do instead is to form a new string with slices. So, take all character before position `34`, then add character for position `34` and, then add all characters after position `34`. Note that strings are *immutable* in python.

2. Calling `A.write(f)` does not make sense. Here `A` is the original file content and `f` is the modified file content. Both are *strings*. Writing to file would be something like

```py
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(content, file=f)
```

3. The input is not sanitized. If user gives more than one character, all characters are taken. (could be how you wanted, or not)

#### One possible solution

You could do something like this:

```py
def change_character(filename, n=35):

    content = get_file_content(filename)
    if content is None:
        return

    newchar = get_new_char()

    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        print(content[: n - 1], file=f, end="")
        print(newchar, file=f, end="")
        print(content[n + 1 :], file=f, end="")
```

#### Usage example

```
change_character("somefile.txt", n=35)
```

#### Helper functions

```
def get_file_content(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            return f.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found")


def get_new_char():
    newchar = input("\nEnter New Character: ")
    if len(newchar) > 1:
        newchar = newchar[0]
        print(
            f"More than one character supplied. Using the first character ({newchar})"
        )
    return newchar
```